# Deleting some elements in an array in OpenCL kernel code

Tags: opencl

After compacting an array(putting required elements from an input array into an output array) by doing a scan operation, there might be some empty spaces left in the output(compacted) array in a contiguous form after the required elements are placed. Is there a way to free these empty spaces in the OpenCL kernel code itself without going back in the host(just for the sake of deleting)...?

for eg I have an input array of 100 elements with some no.s greater than 50 and some of them less than 50 and want to store the no.s more than 50 in a different array and do further processing only on those elements in that array, and I don't know the size of this output array since I don't know how many no.s are actually greater than 50(so I declare the size of this array to be 100)... then after performing a scan I get the output array with all elements more than 50... but there might be some continuous spaces empty in the output array after the storage of these elements... then how do we delete these spaces... Is there a way of doing this in the kernel code itself...? Or do we have to come back in the Host code for this...?

How do we deal with such compacted arrays to do further processing if we can't delete the remaining spaces in the kernel code itself and also if we don't want to go back in the host code..?

Comment: You cannot change the length of arrays or size of dynamic data structures inside the kernel. If you intend to resize the array to save some space, you will need to resize the array in the host. I am not sure "just for the sake of deleting" is going to be a good enough reason to do what you want to do. What *do* you want to do, by the way? A typical way to implicitly remove those empty spaces is to sort the array so that all empty spaces are at the beginning (or end), find out the number of valid elements and their start point, and use that in your kernel to process only a section of the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution to your problem I'm afraid.

What I think you might do, is to have a counter of the elements in each array. You can increment the counter first locally with atomic_inc() and then globally with atomic_add().
This way at the end of your kernel execution the total number of elements in each array will be present.

You can also use this atomic operation as an index for the array. This way you can write to the output without any "hole" in your array. However you will probably lose some speed due to abusing of atomic operations I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't have any holes in between the array... the empty spaces are at the end itself, as I have performed a scan operation on my input array as mentioned above. I just wanted to know a way of deleting the elements placed after the reuired elements are placed...!

I want to this because if have some spaces empty at the end, this harms the GPU performance as some threads remain idle and use some GPU memory stays occupied unnecessarily...!

Comment: By another way I meant to say that is there any way of setting limits on actually how many threads will perform over an array? for eg I have 100 element array, but I make only 50 threads operate on them...? Is there any such way of limiting the ends of global size...?

Comment: If you already know the number of elements, and the elements are at the begining of the array. Then the solution is trivial. Having a big array and using only the begining does not harm your speed at all. Just shrink the global size to the new needed size.

Comment: But, I don't know the size before, this size will be calculated inside the kernel...!

Comment: Then use the atomic_inc() to count the number of elements in each array.